# paired.r Function - Correct degrees of freedom?

Tags: r, statistics

I have a dataset in which I am testing for a significant difference between two dependent correlations. For example, I examined the correlations between variables X and Z (corXZ) and between variables Y and Z (corYZ), and also want to know if corXZ and corYZ are significantly different, taking into account the correlation between X and Y (corXY).

I have been using the R function paired.r, which generally works very well. But, as you can see, it does not provide the degrees of freedom in the output, simply a t-value:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/psych/versions/1.7.8/topics/paired.r

For the purposes of reporting such tests in a manuscript, I need to provide the accurate degrees of freedom. How do I find this or calculate this?

Answer (score 1):

For the test with a third (yz) correlation specified, the degrees of freedom are = n-3 :

```
> # install.packages("psych")
> library(psych)
> 
> n = 100
> paired.r(.5,.3, .4, n = n)
Call: paired.r(xy = 0.5, xz = 0.3, yz = 0.4, n = n)
[1] "test of difference between two correlated  correlations"
t = 2.06  With probability =  0.04

> 2 * pt(q = 2.06, df = n-3, lower.tail = F) # 2 tailed p value
[1] 0.04207664


> n = 10
> paired.r(.5,.3, .4, n = n)
Call: paired.r(xy = 0.5, xz = 0.3, yz = 0.4, n = n)
[1] "test of difference between two correlated  correlations"
t = 0.56  With probability =  0.6

> 2 * pt(q = 0.56, df = n-3, lower.tail = F)
[1] 0.5929396
>
```

The nice point with open source software like `R` is that you can always inspect the source code to answer this kind of question. Here you can simply type `paired.r` in the console (without parentheses) in the console to obtain the source code...

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and for pasting that example! I really appreciate your time to help me out with this! You are awesome.  :)

Comment: Glad that it helps... Please consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)